# $L_2$ distance and Hellinger distance

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

I am a little confused: what are the difference betwen Hellinger distance
$$d_H(f,g)^2 = \int(\sqrt{f} - \sqrt{g})^2\:\mathrm d x$$
and the $L_2$ distance
$$L_2(f,g)^2 = \int(f - g)^2\:\mathrm dx.$$
It seems like both are basically the same except that the Hellinger distance considers the square roots of the functions at hand.

Apparently the Hellinger distance is just a special case of the $L_2$ distance (by restricting to the square roots of nonnegative functions). So why is the Hellinger distance a thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the section 20.4 of the book  "Markov Chains and Mixing Times (2nd edition)" written by David A.Levin and Yuval Peres. This distance has some relation with the total variance distance (see wiki page) and behaves well under tensor products, Theroem 20.7. in the aforementioned reference uses this distance to obtain good bound on the mixing time for continuous time product Markov chains (but the state space is finite there).